# How to track Will on Nobilis 3rd edition character sheet?

Tags: character-sheets, nobilis

Reading the Nobilis 3rd edition book, I noticed the character sheet at the end does not include any place to write the current Will of the character.

I understand that Nobles will still use mortal actions when they want to keep a low profile or are out of their Estate properties or have a very low Aspect attribute.

**Is it necessary to track will? If so, how should I do that?**